# Calculate field from Colour values of bivariate symbology using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, fields-attributes

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I made a Bivariate Symbology (3X3 Grid) for a map. Therefore, I have 9 color values now.

I want to assign those colour values or an alias, in the attribute table.

For example. The Pink colour of the symbology will be filled as "Low Low" in a new field of the attribute table. The Violet colour will be shown as High High, and so on.

I want to make represent the symbology in a Tabulated Form. Therefore I am trying to convert that small 3X3 grid legend into a detailed table.

Comment: Have you seen https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/mapping/layer-properties/bivariate-colors.htm ?

Comment: Yes @aldo_tapia, I have checked the link. Did you understood the my question? After applying the bivariate symbology, I want to separate each colour in a different layer. Or, have the colour name/ value stored in the field of attribute table for each entity.

Comment: Ahh, got it. You need to check color breaks for both fields and then use field calculator assigning classes based on breaks

Comment: @aldo_tapia, can you tell me the steps for assigning classes based on breaks? Do I need write a script? I don't know coding.